«Когда-то» в будущем времени
Правильно ли использовать "когда-то", если речь идёт про будущее?
Пример: Если список когда-то дополнят, то меня туда, скорее всего, не добавят.
Или предпочтительнее использовать всё-таки "когда-нибудь"?

• В толковом словаре имеется вот что:
когда-то, наречие
1. Некогда в прошлом. Когда-то по берегам Дона росли вековые дубравы.
2. Неизвестно когда в будущем, ещё нескоро. Улита едет — когда-то будет (посл.).
• Имеются примеры
Этим я утешаю себя, потому что теряю веру и в то, что когда-то определится, наконец, мое положение, когда-то будут, наконец, добрые вести от тебя (Н. И. Гаген-Торн. Memoria).
«Так всегда было, и трудно представить, что когда-то будет иначе», — думал он (Максим Горький. Жизнь Клима Самгина).
Это моя манера, я нашёл! Эта картина когда-то будет стоить миллионы. Причём отнюдь не рублей (Татьяна Соломатина. Большая собака, или «Эклектичная живописная вавилонская повесть о зарытом»).
✦ Имеется и вывод
Никто не запрещает «использовать "когда-то", если речь идёт про будущее»:
Если список когда-то дополнят, то меня туда, скорее всего, не добавят.
Ошибки, конечно, не будет, но будет, считаю, стилистическая неточность.
Она связана с употреблением этого наречия в деловом языке, который по определению не предполагает использования значений «неизвестно когда в будущем, ещё нескоро». Здесь все конкретно, четко, с оговоренными сроками.
Так что, думаю, «предпочтительнее использовать всё-таки "когда-нибудь"».

Ну, легкий диссонанс это и правда вызывает. ("когда-то" это какой-то конкретный момент времени. Соответственно применительно к будущему тут возникают некоторые вопросы) Хотя можно придумать и фразы без диссонанса. Никаких лингвистических запретов тут быть по идее не должно. Смотрите сами, можно заменить "когда-то" на "в какой-то момент". Специфика слов не меняется (в отличии от замены на "когда-нибудь"), а фраза начинает прекрасно звучать:
Если список в какой-то момент дополнят, то... // тут все благозвучно
Когда-то список все равно дополнят // тут все благозвучно


Могу предположить, что наречие  когда-то в будущем времени носит отчасти разговорный характер и дополнительную коннотацию:
Улита едет — когда-то будет (посл.).
Сравнить: Улита едет — когда-нибудь да будет (то есть все-таки приедет).
Местоимение ТО указывает на событие в будущем, которое в принципе возможно, но в  наречии когда-нибудь неопределенность времени этого события выражена явно (нейтральный стиль).
Поэтому использовать когда-то в будущем времени нужно с учетом стиля речи.
